# Can't insert into a table table all of a sudden

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've verified that I am connect with the following:

```
$dbh=MYSQL_CONNECT(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) OR _log("message.php: Can not connected to database.");

if (!$dbh)
{
$test = "Database is not connected.";
}
else{
$test = "All is not good. You're connected.";
}

<?php echo $test; ?>
```

I just noticed that when this file is run, it's no longer inserting the given values into the database table. Here's the query:

```
@mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or _log("message.php:  Can not select database.");


$date=date("Y/m/d H:i:s");

$sql="insert into uploadedtovimeovideos set ifvisible='1', name ='$name', email='$email', occasion='$occasion', recipientName='$recipientName', recipientEmail='$recipientEmail', file='$file', subject='$subject', video='$fileName',msg='$msg', title='$msg', token='$token', date='$date', timezone='$timezone', datescheduled='$dateschedule', password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

_log($sql);
```

No code from this file had changed, but just to be sure, I restored an old version that I know for sure worked, but it didn't help. Also, I've had no problems inserting values into other tables. I checked and the last entry into the table was yesterday around 4, but I have no idea what could have happened after that.

Are there any common problems associated with only one table? What should I be looking for?

Comment: what does `mysql_error()` give you?

Comment: Why are you suppressing errors with the `@` and how many records are in your db? Any messages in your logs?

Comment: Christian, you might want to anonymize the log results before posting them in a comment. I deleted the previous one that had names and emails in it.

Comment: show the output of $SQL on the failed attempt (removing specific info).  My guess is one of the text values has a special character which is generating the error.  Good reason to move to paramaratized queries

Comment: Thanks andrewsi. The mysql_error revealed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `mysql_query`, try appending your `or _log(mysql_error())` function to it.

Secondly, you shouldn't be using any `mysql_*` functions. Instead, use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: Good recommendations, but neither of your suggestions actually answers why his insert fails. Should probably be a comment.

Comment: Phew..heart attack is over. I deleted an unnecessary field that was still in the query. I just took it out of the query.

Comment: @j08691 I agree; but while the recommendation of appending the `or` statement may just be a comment, I posted it as an answer which would help the user identify and solve the problem. Glad you got it figured out!